# EmberJS can't find route

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm new to EmberJS and following this tutorial:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/

Currently I've this file structure:

```
index.html
static/js/app.js
static/js/compononents
static/js/controllers/usersController.js
static/js/handlebars-v1.1.2.js
static/js/helpers
static/js/models/user.js
static/js/router.js
static/js/routes/usersRoute.js
static/js/store.js
static/js/templates/application.hbs
static/js/templates/index.hbs
static/js/templates/user.hbs
static/js/templates/users.hbs
static/js/views/
```

Currently I've got all the code until the 'SINGLE USER ROUTE'-part.

I've exactly followed the tutorial, but when I go http://ember.lusenet.com/#/users , I get the error 'Assertion failed: The URL '/users' did not match any routes in your application'. I really don't know what's going wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As far as I can see in the URL provided, all other files, except for app.js, aren't included into the index.html file. No doubt it won't find #/users/ without routes included.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit ? your app.js file only has:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
```

Doesnt seem like grunt is properly concatenating your JS files.

Comment: I don't use the Ember App Kit and you're right, I don't have a grunt-file. I  was looking at the Github you posted but I can't figure out which file does the concatenating. Do you have any suggestions?